# Firebase email verification expires immediately

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing a firebase web project where user can sign up and login via email / password.

Right now, when I send a verification email (`firebase.auth().currentUser.sendEmailVerification()`).

When I receive the email (few seconds later) and follow the link, I just get this error:

[image]

However, my email is still not verified - and there are no further error messages. How can I complete the email verification?

Retrying the procedure gives me a different link each time, but with the same result.

Comment: Can you check your underlying network errors in the browser console? I suspect this has to do with your API key.

Comment: There are no errors in the browser console. Since it is a public API key (used in web application - [should be fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public) ), I restricted the APIs to which the key has access, but there is no "access denied" error or the like.

Comment: There must be some underlying API request error. Check the browser console. They won't show this screen without an error.

Comment: Fixed it; it was an API which I disabled for the API key. After enabling identity toolkit and token service api and dynamic links api, it worked again. Don't know yet which API exactly was required.